# json response in jquery alert

Tags: json, jquery

```
{
    user: [
      {
          id: 476,
          customer: {
            id: "375",
            name: "test",
            avatar: null,
            email: "test@test.com",
            phone_number: "",
            created_at: "2013-06-19 19:47:54.425111"
        },
        service: "test",
        inst: "N/A",
        images: [ ]
      }]
}
```

How do I print the above json in my jQuery

I tried following to get the json

```
$.getJSON('jobs.json', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

This returns the json but when i print the service it is throwing error

```
$.getJSON('jobs.json', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.service[0]);
});
```

Throwing error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data.user[0].service);
```

Comment: He wants to print it in alert

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {
user: [
  {
      id: 476,
      customer: {
        id: "375",
        name: "test",
        avatar: null,
        email: "test@test.com",
        phone_number: "",
        created_at: "2013-06-19 19:47:54.425111"
    },
    service: "test",
    inst: "N/A",
    images: [ ]
  }]
};
console.log(json);
alert(json.user[0]['service']);
```

this will alert "test".

Answer (score 0):

U dont need to stringyfy:

```
     alert(data.user[0].service)
```